# Fitting & Resizing Photo within Portion of Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS, and I'm currently working on a project where I have a vertical menu. When I try to fit my full-size background image, it extends the width of the screen so I need to scroll for it. I need to cover the remainder of the white-space on the page, but without having this happen.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Ryan Gross: Web Dev. </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
            }
            body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                font-family:"Verdana";
                overflow:auto;
            }
            #menu_background {
                float:left;
                background-color:#272727;
                width:200px;
                height:100%;
                position:fixed;
            }
            #side_menu {
                list-style-type:none;
                font-size:1.3em;
                width:200px;
                padding:0px;
                margin-top:260px;
                font-family:"Verdana";
                text-align:center;
            }
            #side_menu li a {
                display:block;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#E6E6E6;
                padding:8px 0px 8px 0px;
            }
            #side_menu li a:hover {
                background-color:#585858;
            }
            #contact_info {
                float:left;
                margin:120px 0px 0px 20px;
                padding:0;
                color:#E6E6E6;
                list-style-type:none;
                font-size:.9em;
            }
            #contact_info li {
                padding:2px 0px 2px 0px;
            }
            #image {
                float:left;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background-size:cover;
                background-image:url("example.jpg");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <div class="container">
        <div id="menu_background"> 
            <ul id="side_menu">
                <li> <a href="about.html">  About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="skills.html">  Skills </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="projects.html">  Projects </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="resume.html"> Resume </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="image"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it extending ***beyond*** the width of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the #image height to `height:100vh` which means you want it to stretch to 100% of the viewport height. You can find more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Here is the new code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: Verdana
}

#side_menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

#menu_background {
  float: left;
  background-color: #272727;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed
}

#side_menu {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 260px;
  text-align: center;
}

#side_menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

#side_menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #585858
}

#image {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/1500) no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


  <div id="menu_background">

    <ul id="side_menu">
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="image"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#image{
background: url('http://www.natureasia.com/common/img/splash/thailand.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the page responsive and to fix your issue, you can set the width of your navigation to 20% and the width of your image to 80%. This will allow the two to float beside each other. The only trick will be that you will want to set break points if you are using smaller screens. Here is the new code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="container">
        <div id="menu_background"> 
            <ul id="side_menu">
                <li> <a href="about.html">  About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="skills.html">  Skills </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="projects.html">  Projects </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="resume.html"> Resume </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="image"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:"Verdana";
overflow:auto;
}

#menu_background {
float:left;
background-color:#272727;
width:20%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
}

#side_menu {
list-style-type:none;
font-size:1.3em;
width:200px;
padding:0px;
margin-top:260px;
font-family:"Verdana";
text-align:center;
}


#side_menu li a {
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#E6E6E6;
padding:8px 0px 8px 0px;

}

#side_menu li a:hover {
background-color:#585858;
}


#contact_info {
float:left;
margin:120px 0px 0px 20px;
padding:0;
color:#E6E6E6;
list-style-type:none;
font-size:.9em;
}

#contact_info li {
padding:2px 0px 2px 0px;
}

#image {
float:right;
width:80%;
height:100%;
background-size:cover;
background-image:url("example.jpg");
}
```